# How to keep multiple, separated divs at equal height regardless of the content inside

Tags: css, height

*Note: This is a follow-up I have to a previous question, "CSS - how to set the height of a div when a nested divs height is set to fit-content?" (thank you Farshad Vaghari for providing the answer to that). In fact, because this depended on the answer to that previous question, I'll be using the code Farshad Vaghari provided as their answer as the basis for this next question.*

Hi all,

Say I have two divs, each inside a separate flex container. Now, suppose one div has twice the amount of content as the other, and so the code currently looks like this:

```css
.outerDiv {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: darkblue;
  width: 400px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 106px;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px darkblue solid;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px darkblue solid;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.div1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  width: 250px;
}

#divContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#divContainer-left {
  flex: 50%;
}

#divContainer-right {
  flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="divContainer">
  <div id="divContainer-left">
    <div class="outerDiv">
      <div class="box1">
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
      </div>
      <div class="div1" contenteditable="true" style="outline: none;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. At consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Massa
        tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque. Vestibulum
        sed arcu non odio euismod.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="divContainer-right">
    <div class="outerDiv">
      <div class="box1">
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
      </div>
      <div class="div1" contenteditable="true" style="outline: none;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. At consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Massa
        tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque. Vestibulum
        sed arcu non odio euismod. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor. At consectetur
        lorem donec massa sapien. Massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida. Molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque. Nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in. Quisque non tellus orci ac auctor
        augue mauris augue neque. Vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, the divs `box1` and `box2` must remain underneath the div `div1` at all times.

Since I intend to make multiple instances of this and don't know which divs out of all of them will hold the most content, how do I set the height of `divContainer-left` and `divContainer-right` to be equal to whichever of them is the tallest?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using "display:grid;"  and its other properties you can learn about it at w3school

```css
.outerDiv {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: cyan;
  width: 400px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 106px;
}

.outerDiv div {
  color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px darkblue solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box1 {
  background: black;
}

.box2 {
  background: purple;
}

.box3 {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="divContainer-right">
  <div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="box1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident
      similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit, tenetur error, harum nesciunt ipsum debitis quas aliquid.
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should really try to learn display grid , its very useful